# Pub Sub message taking time from Publisher to Subscriber

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a frequently used pub sub queue with one pull subscription (a listener) attached to it. In certain random times of the day, the messages in the queue take more time to reach the subscription. Is there any specific reason or scenario that I should consider here to ensure delivery? Ordering key is enabled in the subscription.

Comment: Hi @vzurd ,  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Pub/Sub guarantees message delivery. Cloud Pub/Sub provides high throughput, low latency and
consistently delivers messages in a couple of seconds at the 99th
percentile.But high latency in Cloud Pub/Sub can have multiple reasons. Listing below few of the reasons for the high latency :

- Major reason for delay can be the rate at which the subscriber
  processes messages and also requests more messages.
- The type of subscription also plays a role in latency.In pull
  subscription, a subscriber returns multiple responses whereas in push
  subscription, subscriber returns HTTP responses.For more details you
  can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push_pull).
- Another reason can be where you are running your publisher and
  subscriber as if you are not running it in Google Cloud Platform,
  then the network latency between your server and Google Server can
  also be one of the reasons.
- One more reason can be the batching of the messages. If you are using
  batching then also latency increases as mentioned in this
  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching). To minimize the latency, turn off the batching.
- [Message flow control](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#flow_control) also plays an important role in latency.One
  client is having backlog of messages as it could not further process
  incoming messages due to not having capacity of processing the volume
  of incoming messages but the other client who is having  more
  capacity could not process the messages as the first client maintains
  lease on the messages it receives which increases latency as messages
  get stuck on first client.
- As the client library repeatedly extends acknowledgement deadline,
  backlogged messages deadline which consumes memory, CPU and bandwidth
  due to which the subscriber client might run out of resources and
  lead to high latency.
- Ordering key might increase latency since if message ordering property is set, then the  Pub/Sub service delivers messages which happens according to the order of the same ordering key that the Pub/Sub service receives the messages which might increase the latency.

Comment: My subscription is in compute engine in the same region and cpu utilization is minimal. Does ordering key have anything to do with it

Comment: Hi @vzurd, I have updated my answer. Please check